# Python sqlite3 unable to open database on atom

Tags: python, database, macos, sqlite, atom-editor

so I have a program which runs perfectly on my Windows operated laptop, however, I switched to macOS and a lot of errors have come up in response to that. One of the hardest to tackle is the following:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect(“Inventory.db”)

sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

This was never a problem with my Windows operated system, and it seems that the problem is not macOS itself, but atom. I ran this same code on IDLE and it worked perfectly. I am assuming it has something to do with permission to create new files but I am not sure.
Help please!

Comment: You might have different current working folders. Using the full path to the file should help.

Comment: Dude I need to thank you somehow but I can't find the upvote button. Thank you very much! I had tried this already but then I forgot I had to use double slash.